# C# WCT ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete

Tags: c#, wcf, transactions

Im sure I understand those properties all wrong.

1. ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete -
   from what I understood- dispose your service instance that you initilize in your client after your transaction there complete\abord.

2.TransactionAutoComplete-
from what I understood- dispose your service instance that you initilize in your client after the opertion ended.

My english isnt that good so after reading each article, I still have peaces that i dont understand.

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT 1:**

Can you expline to me in simple english what is the purpose of InstanceContext? 
I have read this article : http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/05/23/understanding-instancecontext-in-wcf/
and still didnt get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete` really disposes your service instance when the transaction is completed or aborted. It is by default set to true. If you for example create service with PerSession instancing you may want to turn it to false to ensure your session lifetime instead of transaction lifetime.

`TransactionAutoComplete` has nothing to do with disposing. It just controls transaction used to execute operation. If `TransactionScopeRequired` is set to true, your operation will be automatically wrapped by `TransactionScope`. `TransactionAutoComplete` set to true will than automatically commit transaction if the operation executes without error or rollback transaction if operation throws exception. If you set `TransactionAutoComplete` to false you will have to commit transaction manually by calling:

```
OperationContext.Current.SetTransactionComplete();
```

Comment: I set ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete =true and after the transaction from my client was completed, I could keep coulding more methods from my service. how is that? second thing, when I creat Tran'Scope in client and then call some methods in service and they have TransactionScopeRequired =true, when those methods start, they use the client's tran'Scope or creat new one? if yes, why they do that? if no, why the hell would I want to turn them off by setttinng TransactionAutoComplete =true? then I cant keep calling other methods from client in my client Tran'Scope.